# 8 bit arduinos: What happens to the data in registers during a function call? During an interupt?

Tags: avr

If I have one function that uses registers heavily calling another that does the same thing, what happens?  Does the data get destroyed?  What, then, would happen on return to the first function?  Is this different for interrupt handlers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is capable of analyzing which registers are used by the function or ISR, so it generates prologue and epilogue code that saves the registers on the stack on entry and restores them on exit.

Comment: Is it any different for regular functions?

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky: Nope.